# Can I Use .htaccess in Magento 2 to Redirect All Sites in Domain Except the Current Site

Tags: .htaccess, magento2

I'm working on a Magento 2 store, and I need to implement a redirect strategy. Specifically, I want to redirect all customers to the homepage of the store. I've already redirected 404 pages to a landing page through the admin section (Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web) by setting the CMS No Route Page.

However, now I need to redirect the entire site to the same landing page, excluding the current site. I'm unsure about how to achieve this in Magento 2 Admin.

I'm considering using .htaccess for this purpose since Magento 2 typically points to pub/index.php. I've come across some .htaccess code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This code appears to work, but when I visit [www.newdomain.com](http://www.newdomain.com), I encounter an error related to multiple redirects. If I don't use this method, I'll have to write an Observer to handle the redirection.

Can someone advise me on whether using .htaccess for this purpose is feasible in Magento 2? If so, how can I modify the .htaccess rules to achieve the desired redirection without encountering multiple redirect errors? Alternatively, if an Observer is a more appropriate solution, could you provide some guidance on how to implement it effectively?

Thank you

Comment: "This works" - how does the rule you posted not redirect the "current site"? "but If I visit www.newdomain.com I get Error regarding multiple redirects" - That rule redirects _everything_, change the regex so that it only redirects _something_.

Comment: Please clarify, are you trying to redirect to the root document under the same domain, or are you trying to redirect to a _new_ domain? And if the latter, what is your setup - do you have _both_ domains currently pointing to the same magento instance on your server?